# iPhone vs Android web site sizes

Tags: android, iphone, css, web

I'm trying to adjust [my web site](http://olalindberg.com/) to work for both android and iphone. I've set up almost everything to scale down in width.

When I test it by resizing my own web browser window it works as expected. 
When I view it on my iphone it works fine. 
But when I view it on android (or on the android emulator) it looks different from the others.
I attach two screen shots.

I have no idea where to start... Thanks in advance.

[image: Android emulator]

[image: iPhone]

Comment: Can you post some example code on, say, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It's very hard to debug CSS\HTML without a working example, especially a fluid layout.

Comment: Hi, sorry. The site is live here http://olalindberg.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try reseting your font in the body. body { font-size: 100%; } Also, try using viewport see http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly simple reason the Android emulator looks different: it's because how wide you've set the emulator's screen to be. In your CSS file, you've set the page's `min-width` to be 600 pixels, which is larger than the Android emulator's width is. This causes the header to get truncated.

I'm no web designer, so how you choose to handle a design for such a small width is up to you. However, you can target such edge cases with the following within your CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    // Some CSS code
}
```

Or, with a separate stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 600px)" href="android-stylesheet.css" />
```